# how to keep a margin between the footer and the content?

Tags: html, css

hello am trying to make a centralized website with the footer at the bottom and the problem is there is no margins between the footer div and the content div the footer is overlapping the content but when I zoom out the page the problem is fixed however another problem came which is the content height is not full here is a link with the website uploaded so you can see the problem

http://yandothebluffer66.net23.net/

and here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Untitled 1</title>

<style type="text/css">
html,
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
}
#header {
background:#292929;
height : 100px;
}
#content {
padding-bottom:100px; /* Height of the footer element */
width: 1000px;
margin : 50px auto;
min-height: 80%;;
background: black;
overflow: hidden;
}
#footer {
background:#292929;
width:100%;
height:100px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="bigwrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <img src="images/stuff%20for%20sale/9.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
</body>

 </html>
```

Comment: i think it will work like you want if you change the footer's `position` to `relative`

Comment: yeah I know but if I did then when you zoom out the footer will be no longer at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title>Untitled 1</title>
    
    <style type="text/css">
    html,
    body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    }
    #bigwrapper{height:100%;}
    #wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    }
    #header {
    background:#292929;
    height : 100px;
    min-height:8%;
    }
    #content {
    width: 80%;
    margin : 50px auto;
    background: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    #footer {
    background:#292929;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    min-height:8%;
    position:inherit;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    
    }
    
    
    </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div id="bigwrapper">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="content">
            <img src="http://yandothebluffer66.net23.net/images/stuff%20for%20sale/9.jpg" width="100%">
        </div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    
     </html>
```

Comment: this leads to another problem the footer is overlapping the content from the beginning also still no margin between the footer and the content and if you zoom in the footer will overlap the whole content so its connected to the header

Comment: remove position in css.

Comment: what how is that ?

Comment: give position inherit; in #footer

Comment: this solved half of the problem now there is margin between content and footer but if you zoom out the footer will not stay at the bottom of the page

Comment: Yeah this is nice but if you zoom out at some point the margin between the content and the footer will be disappeared as you continue zooming out it will come back but the content size is no full  its not reaching the footer with a little margin in between

Answer (score 0):

```
#content {
width: 1000px;
margin : 50px auto;
min-height: 80%;
background: black;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Remove the padding and your main problem is fixed
You can also set "position:absolute;" in the footer to make that part fix

Comment: I set the position back to absolute and remove padding still the same problem

Comment: you set aboslute in the footer, right?
it worked for me when i tried it

Comment: can you post it on snippet ?